# javascript xml cross-domain mess - how to go around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, cross-domain

I'm a real noob in js. I've seen a lot of questions about this, but none of them seems got it clear to me. They all falls into json, that is not available.
I'm trying to access a very poorly documented [API](http://www2.camara.leg.br/transparencia/dados-abertos/dados-abertos-legislativo/dados-abertos-legislativo)(it is in portuguese...). It does not support Json nor Jsonp. It is only xml, via  SOAP, HTTP GET e HTTP POST. And of course I'm getting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.camara.gov.br/SitCamaraWS/Deputados.asmx/ObterDeputados.
>   Origin http://kubrusly.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

my code is:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://www.camara.gov.br/SitCamaraWS/Deputados.asmx/ObterDeputados",
dataType: "xml",
success: parseXml
});
```

When working locally this goes fine, but once uploaded to my server, it won't retrieve nothing...
Curious enough if i try `dataType: "jsonp"` :P i get an error complaining about unexpected char '<'. And the xml doc is visible in Safari's console. So the data, in xml format, is arriving in browser, it is there, but i can't access it...

So if json is not an option, how can i go to retrieve this data? It is so frustrating.

I pasted the testing code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/HwP2S/1/

@Kevin B
Thanks for your answer. I did a little research on CORS. I got a little confused with that. Is this supposed to happend on the client side? Any way I got an .htaccess from html5 boilerplate, uncommented the

[EDIT] - solved.

Ok, so I get it going, thanks for the help of you guys. I'll let my solution registered here...

I found that CORS stuff is done in the server side, not my case.
I did not try YQL, you know one more variable, syntax... I let this for last, but did not need it.
I managed to set a proxy and go through it, i spend a lot of time before setting the user agent, and that did it. Before that I aways got 403 error...

[this](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) page from yahoo, helped my a lot, some good code examples, both js and PHP.

here the code that is working for me:

**js:**

```
    // Based on script from yahoo's example @ http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/samples/ajax/sample_proxy_ajax.html
    // tweaked by vk

// end point without domain...
var endPtpath = '/SitCamaraWS/Deputados.asmx/ObterDeputados?';

//  PHP proxy
var proxiedUrl = 'http://kubrusly.com/yxd/php_proxy_simple.php?yws_path=' + encodeURIComponent(endPtpath);

// mind browsers... 
var xmlhttp = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //overrideMimeType if supported
        if ( typeof xmlhttp.overrideMimeType != 'undefined') { xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml'); }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }  else {
        alert('Perhaps your browser does not support xmlhttprequests?');
      }

// Create an HTTP GET request
xmlhttp.open('GET', proxiedUrl, true);

// Set the callback function
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                // Output the results
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
              } else {
                // waiting for the call to complete
            console.log("waiting...");
          }
        };

// Make the actual request
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// PHP Proxy --- only 'GET'
// Based on script from yahoo's example @ http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/samples/proxy/php_proxy_simple.txt
// tweaked by vk
//  hostname - just base domain
define ('HOSTNAME', 'http://www.camara.gov.br');

// Get the REST call path from the AJAX application - js;
$path = $_GET['yws_path'];

// assign yo url
$url = HOSTNAME.$path;

//Open the Curl session
$session = curl_init($url);

// Don't return HTTP headers. Do return the contents of the call
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

//set user agent, that did it!!! copied from browsers...
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36');

// The web service returns XML. Set the Content-Type appropriately
header("Content-Type: text/xml");


//// verbose mode for debuging good tool!
// $fp_err = fopen('verbose_file.txt', 'ab+');
// fwrite($fp_err, date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n\n"); //add timestamp to theverbose log
// curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
// curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp_err);


// Make the call
$xml = curl_exec($session);

// done, shutDown.
curl_close($session);
?>
```

Comment: the "YQL console" can convert the API's XML into jsonp for you...

Comment: If you don't have CORS support, you must use a proxy if you wish to request xml cross-domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: @Kevin B Thanks. I edited the question with my finds based in your hint, if u care to have a look at and see if you can help me any further... thanks.

Comment: You will need to use a proxy. Headers will need to be placed on `http://www.camara.gov.br`, which you probably do not have access to.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes more sense... thanks. Yep no access. How to make a proxy? Is it in php? It belongs in the index.html? Is possible to construct the query programatically in js? What should i look for? Thanks

Comment: edited the question with the answer that worked for me.HTH someone tks all Why the js code did'n get highlighted?